# Even if i serve media files with nginx, they don't appear on the website

Tags: python, django, nginx, media

I am trying to use nginx to put my django app on production. But I cannot use images in the website even though I configured nginx.
My nginx server's setup:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

location /static/ {
        root /home/myusername/myproject/static/;
}

location /media/ {
        root /home/myusername/myproject/media/;
}

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

The path that the images are saved:

```
/home/myusername/myproject/media/images/
```

My html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="column">
    {% for dweet in dweets %}
        <div class="box">
            {{dweet.body}}
            <span class="is-small has-text-grey-light">
                ({{ dweet.created_at }} from {{ dweet.user.username }})
            </span>
            <figure>
            <img class="is-rounded" src="/media/{{dweet.image}}" alt="connect" style="max-height:300px">
            </figure>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>



{% endblock content %}
```

I have played around with directory paths, but still nothing.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Dweet
from django.db import models
from django.forms import fields
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class DweetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    body = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.widgets.Textarea(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": " ...",
                "class": "textarea is-success is-medium",
            }
        ),
        label="",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Dweet
        fields  = ['body', 'image']
        exclude = ("user",)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

...

class Dweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             related_name="dweets",
                             on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null='True')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='dweet_like')

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f"{self.user} "
            f"({self.created_at:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}): "
            f"{self.body[:30]}..."
        )
```

views.py

```
from .forms import DweetForm, NewUserForm
from .models import Dweet, Profile
from django.shortcuts import  render, redirect
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import logout

@login_required
def post(request):
    form = DweetForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            dweet = form.save(commit=False)
            dweet.user = request.user
            dweet.save()
            return redirect("dwitter:dashboard")

    return render(
        request,
        "dwitter/post.html",
        {"form": form},
    )

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    followed_dweets = Dweet.objects.filter(
        user__profile__in=request.user.profile.follows.all()
    ).order_by("-created_at")

    return render(
        request,
        "dwitter/dashboard.html",
        {"dweets": followed_dweets},
    )
```

I hope that you can understand more about my code with the files I added.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your solution:**

**Note:** *you have to use nginx and gunicorn for this solution*

1. first give permission to static and media folder

   ```
   sudo chmod g+s /var/www/mysite
   sudo chmod o-rwx /var/www/mysite
   ```
2. Next you have to configure nginx ***"mysite.conf"***

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf
   ```
3. write this code in ***"mysite.conf"***

   ```
   server {
   listen 80;
   server_name <domain name or ip>;

   location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
   location /static/{
       autoindex on;
       alias /var/www/mysite/static/;
   }

   location /media/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias /var/www/mysite/media/;
   }

   location / {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
       }
   }
   ```
4. you can check more details here:
   [How to server static and media files in nginx](https://wolfx.io/how-to-serve-static-and-media-files-in-nginx)

Comment: Even though the images I upload go to the right directory, the website doesn't display them while on production.